# How to provide read-only access for unauthorized users to my React/Django app?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have a social media-type web app and want to have some read-only access even when a user isn't logged in. For example, if the user votes on a poll, I want nothing to happen but the user should still be able to see it. I am using token authorization. I'm wondering, should I do a check on the front-end somehow to see if a user is logged in (perhaps checking for the existence of a token in local storage) and not perform a fetch if they're not? Or should I somehow, in the frontend, handle receiving a 401 response from the backend for trying to access a protected resource? Or should I handle it on the back end and send back a 200 response and let the front end handle receiving a different version of a 200 response?

I'm using Django and React

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question has tag *django-rest-framework* so I suppose you are using it.

Take a look at [DRF permissions documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#permissions). There is `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` permission which allows read-only access for unauthenticated users (`list`, `retrieve` actions), but only allows `create`, `update`, `delete` to authenticated users.